# Failed to get Imagick load for php7.4

Tags: php, upgrade, imagick

I know there has been a lot of question asked regarding installing imagick to Php7+, unfortunately all the answer doesn't solve my issue.

I just update to php7.4, so I follow the previous setting from 7.3, 7.2 to enabled imagick,
basically:

```
echo extension=imagick.so > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini
```

then soft link to "fpm" and "cli" directory:

```
ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
```

reloaded the php7.4-fpm, but imagick still failed to load

verify with **php -i | grep imagick** but got an error of:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /us
r/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Note:
- I have tried to **purge** php-imagick and reinstall it, but **doesn't work**.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it on my raspi this way (based on the instructions here: [How to Install PHP imagick extension](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-imagemagick-extension/)):

- `sudo apt install php7.4-dev` (if not already installed)
- check your `pecl` Version (must match with 7.4): `pecl version`
- make sure that `sed` is executable from `/bin/sed` (the `pecl install` needs it to be there, I had to symlink it from `/usr/bin/sed`)
- `sudo apt install libmagickwand-dev`
- `sudo pecl install imagick`

Then you can carry on with the steps you already made:

```
sudo echo extension=imagick.so > /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/imagick.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini
```

After that, restart your services (php7.4-fpm, apache, nginx, ...).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

To install Imagick run bellow command:
`sudo apt-get install php-imagick`

For specific PHP version (in my case 7.1):
`sudo apt-get install php7.1-imagick`

Then restart apache:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

To check if the extension has been installed:
`php -m | grep imagick`

Answer (score 2):

Also got this error and took a solid 2 hours to solve:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /phpusr/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Even though `php -i` showed that my configured php version was 7.4 and that imagick extension was installed, I could not get rid of this warning.
So after running alot of commands and reading on the net, I figured the most obvious thing to do is check the given directory `/usr/lib/php/20190902/`.
 So annoyingly even after installing imagick with

```
sudo apt install php-imagick
```

it was not installed in that directory, but was for php8.0. This command

```
apt search imagick
```

had already showed this,

```
php7.4-imagick/focal,now 3.5.1-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 
  Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library

php8.0-imagick/focal,now 3.5.1-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Provides a wrapper to the ImageMagick library
```

but I did not grasp [installed] being missing.
Solution in the end was to **install my configured php version specific imagick** with

```
sudo apt install php7.4-imagick
```

I checked if installed with `php -m | grep imagick` and double checked with `ll /usr/lib/php/20190902` and ran command `sudo systemctl restart apache2` before all was well again.